# Photo rating function

Tags: javascript, react.js, redux

I want to create a photo rating function. If I click thumbs up then votes increase, and if I click thumbs down then votes decrease.

```
function pictures(state = [], action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case ADD_PICTURE:
                return [{
                    id: action.id,
                    picture: action.picture,
                    votes: 0
                    }
            , ...state];
            case LIKE_UP_PICTURE:
                return state.map(picture => {
                    if(picture.id === action.id) {
                    return {...picture, votes: picture.votes + 1}
                    }
                return picture;
                });
            case LIKE_DOWN_PICTURE:
                return state.map(picture => {
                    if(picture.id === action.id) {
                    return {...picture, votes: picture.votes - 1}
                    }
                return picture;
                });
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things you can do and different approaches depending on your personal preference. You could:

### Extract the cases to pure functions

Extracting the logic to methods could help with readability and ease testing.

```
const addPicture = (state, action) => [
  {
    id: action.id,
    picture: action.picture,
    votes: 0,
  },
  ...state,
]

const likeUpPicture = (state, action) =>
  state.map(picture => {
    if (picture.id === action.id) {
      return {
        ...picture,
        votes: picture.votes + 1,
      }
    }

    return picture
  })

const likeDownPicture = (state, action) =>
  state.map(picture => {
    if (picture.id === action.id) {
      return {
        ...picture,
        votes: picture.votes - 1,
      }
    }

    return picture
  })

const pictures = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PICTURE:
      return addPicture(state, action);
    case LIKE_UP_PICTURE:
      return likeUpPicture(state, action);
    case LIKE_DOWN_PICTURE:
      return likeDownPicture(state, action);
  }
}
```

### [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)/[Object shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Destructuring parameters could help signal that from a given action we are only concerned with certain properties. Shorthand notation can help keep the functions concise and reduce duplication.

```
const addPicture = (state, { id, picture }) => [
  {
    id,
    picture,
    votes: 0,
  },
  ...state,
]

const likeUpPicture = (state, { id }) =>
  state.map(picture => {
    if (picture.id === id) {
      return {
        ...picture,
        votes: picture.votes + 1,
      }
    }

    return picture
  })

const likeDownPicture = (state, { id }) =>
  state.map(picture => {
    if (picture.id === id) {
      return {
        ...picture,
        votes: picture.votes - 1,
      }
    }

    return picture
  })
```

### Extract common logic

Since updating a certain element given an id is a common operation extracting the logic to a method might help reduce duplication and increase readability.

```
const updatePicture = (pictures, predicate, callback) =>
  pictures.map(picture => predicate(picture) ? callback(picture) : picture)

const likeUpPicture = (state, action) =>
  updatePicture(state, picture => picture.id === action.id, picture => ({
    ...picture,
    votes: picture.votes + 1,
  }))

const likeDownPicture = (state, action) =>
  updatePicture(pictures, picture => picture.id === action.id, picture => ({
    ...picture,
    votes: picture.votes - 1,
  }))
```

### Define your reducer another way

For example, using [`createReducer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-create-reducer) can result in a compact reducer definition

```
const initialState = []

const pictures = createReducer(initialState, {
  [ADD_PICTURE]: addPicture,
  [LIKE_UP_PICTURE]: likeUpPicture,
  [LIKE_DOWN_PICTURE]: likeDownPicture,
})
```

### [Normalize State Shape](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html)

I've defined the methods inline for brevity but you could extract them as above. The official Redux link above gives a good explanation on why you might want to consider normalizing your state shape.

```
const byId = createReducer({}, {
  [ADD_PICTURE]: (state, { id, picture }) => ({
    ...state,
    [id]: {
      ...picture,
      id,
      votes: 0,
    }
  }),

  [LIKE_UP_PICTURE]: (state, { id }) => ({
    ...state,
    [id]: {
      ...state[id],
      votes: state[id].votes + 1,
    },
  }),

  [LIKE_DOWN_PICTURE]: (state, { id }) => ({
    ...state,
    [id]: {
      ...state[id],
      votes: state[id].votes - 1,
    }
  })
})

const allIds = createReducer([], {
  [ADD_PICTURE]: (state, { id }) => [
    ...state,
    id,
  ],
})

const pictures = combineReducers({
  allIds,
  byIds,
})
```

Comment: under *Exact common logic* heading, the function name would be `addPicture` instead of `updatePicture` #typo

Comment: @pro.mean, the extraction comment proposed that there would be both an addPicture and updatePicture function. The former adds the picture to state while the latter provides a generic function for updating a picture that is already in the state. addPicture was omitted in that section since there was no proposed changes from where it was previously listed

Comment: but in the next code block (reducer defining), you write `addPicture`that's why.

Comment: @pro.mean, I'm not sure I follow. The reducer just maps the action type to the functions. We still want addPicture so that a new picture can be added to the store. updatePicture is just a generic function that likeUpPicture and likeDownPicture expand on - it isn't used in the reducer itself

Comment: oh. got it now. sorry, I miss that. so `addPicture` is exactly same as before and `updatePicture` will be used by rest 2 methods.  one more thing i  would like to know , is this syntax or another way to write object key in caps with array notation >  *[ADD_PICTURE]* is this valid?

Comment: Great! It's using computed property key syntax so that the value of the variable is used as the key. We could have done something like `const x = {}; x[ADD_PICTURE] = addPicture`. We use the variable as the key instead of defining the string again since a typo could very easily get introduced in which case the reducer case wouldn't be caught. This way if we mistype the action type an error would be thrown since the variable wouldn't be defined

Comment: Thank you but I am afraid to say that this is still not clear to me. What I knew that whenever we need to use object key as a variable than we use this way `const x = {}, x[variable_name] = 'whatever'`.But where do we have defined the variable `ADD_PICTURE` in your code or you just typecast it using `[]` to make it valid object key

Comment: Great question! I hadn't included a definition for ADD_PICTURE since the original question didn't include it. It would most likely be defined to be something like `const ADD_TYPE = 'ADD_TYPE'`. So 'ADD_TYPE' will be used as the key. It can be useful to do it this way since if we accidentally typed 'ADD_TYPEE' then the function would not be called because it wouldn't match the action type

Comment: Thanks a lot. now if we have included the definition of ADD_PICTURE than why don't we use directly as `const obj = { ADD_PICTURE:  'whatever' }` instead of `[ADD_PICTURE]`

Comment: We could absolutely do it that way. The drawback is that if you misspelt ADD_PICTURE it might be tricky to debug. By using the variable we are guaranteed it'll be the right value for the key. If we misspell the variable name inside the square brackets that variable won't exist and it'll throw an error